# Sum function using slice only takes first few items

Tags: javascript

I want to get the elements of the array and sum them. I don’t know why but it just takes the first 6 variables. What do I need to do?

```js
function range(start, end) {
  let arr = []

  for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    arr.push(i)
  }

  return arr
}

let arr = range(1, 10)

function sum() {
  let g = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    g += arr.shift()
  }

  return g
}

console.log(sum())
```

Comment: Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs). Try using your browser’s [debug capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a). See [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](/q/25385173/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `sum` function -

```js
function sum() { // ❌ no input parameter
  let g = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) { // ❌ i will go out of bounds
    g += arr.shift() // ❌ arr.shift modifies the length of arr
  }

  return g
}
```

Let's see what happens given a concrete example `arr` -

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
  g += arr.shift()
}
```

| i | arr | i <= arr.length | arr.shift() | g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] | true | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] | true | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | [3,4,5,6,7,8,9] | true | 3 | 6 |
| 3 | [4,5,6,7,8,9] | true | 4 | 10 |
| 4 | [5,6,7,8,9] | true | 5 | 15 |
| 5 | [6,7,8,9] | **false** | *exit loop* | 15 ❌ |

As you can see, `i` exceeds the length of the array after the halfway point has been reached. `g` is only equal to the sum of the first half. To fix it, don't modify the array inside the loop -

```js
function sum(arr) { // ✅ input parameter
  let g = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // ✅ use <
    g += arr[i] // ✅ arr[i] reads element, doesn't modify arr
  }

  return g
}
```

| i | arr | i < arr.length | arr[i] | g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] | true | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] | true | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] | true | 3 | 6 |
| 3 | [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] | true | 4 | 10 |
| 4 | [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] | true | 5 | 15 |
| 5 | [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] | true | 6 | 21 |
| 6 | [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] | true | 7 | 28 |
| 7 | [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] | true | 8 | 36 |
| 8 | [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] | true | 9 | 45 |
| 9 | [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] | **false** | *exit loop* | 45 ✅ |